# $http.delete callback not firing in basic CRUD app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a basic CRUD app, my main problem is with the delete function.

The angular controller calls the $http action

```
'use strict';

(function(){

var app = angular.module('JournalApp', [])
    .controller('JournalController', function($scope, $http){

    var loadEntries = function(){
      $http.get('/api/entry')
          .then(function(response){
            $scope.entries = response.data;
            if(response.data.noEntries){
              $scope.entries.noEntries = true;
            };
          });
    };

  loadEntries();

//Create new Journal Entry
    $scope.addEntry = function(entry){
      var data = ({
        hours: entry.hours,
        notes: entry.notes
      });

      $http.post('/api/entry', data);

        loadEntries();
    };

//Delete Journal Entry
    $scope.delEntry = function(item){

      $http({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: '/api/entry',
        // data: item,
        data: {date: item.date},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf8'}

      }, loadEntries());
    };

  });

})();
```

which is routed to my server side handler

```
  //GET Request
  this.getEntries = function(req, res){
    journal.find().sort({date: -1}).toArray(function(err, doc){
      if(err) throw err;

      if(doc.length){
        console.log('found entries');
        res.json(doc);

      } else {
        console.log('Returning no Entries.')
        res.json(({ "noEntries": true }));
      }
    })
  };

  //Post Request
  this.addEntry = function(req, res){
    console.log('Adding new entry...');

    var time = new Date();
    var notation = req.body.notes || 'n/a'

    journal.insert({ hours: req.body.hours, notes: notation, date: new Date()})
  };

  //Delete Request
  this.deleteEntry = function(req, res){

    journal.findOne({"date": new Date(req.body.date)}, function(err, data){
      if(err) throw err;

      console.log('Removing item _id: ' + data._id);
      journal.remove({"date": data.date});

    });
  };

}

module.exports = entryHandler;
```

I can verify through mongo (and the console.log) that the entry was deleted and everything works as its supposed to. However the $http callback does not fire. The callback function (loadEntries) im using to refresh the journal entires on the page.

I can get the callback to fire when I write the code out as

```
$http.delete('/api/entry', item).then( function(){ loadEntries() } );
```

However when I use this method the server side handler doesnt work properly.

Is there a better way to go about this without a ton of extra modules? I'd  preffer to learn the basics before I start adding packages all over the place doing the work for me.

EDIT:

I've tried adding .then(function(){ loadEntries() }); to my angular code, and it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call .then on your $http call to execute the callback function:

```
$http({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: '/api/entry',
    // data: item,
    data: {date: item.date},
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf8'}

  }).then(function() {
      loadEntries()
  });
```

Comment: I know my code above is different, but your solution was the way I wrote it originally and it did not work. i've re-written it a couple times and have had no success so far. I also just double checked and retried that code, does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to successfully call my callback no matter what I tried. However my goal was to remove div's from my app, so I just used the angular ng-show/hide directive to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from .then(), It looks like server code is not returning any call completion status such as success/failure similar to  - Ok/BadRequest  (IHTTPctionResult type) in C#